# Why does a UITextField have a .text value of Optional("Actual Text") Swift

Tags: swift, uitextfield

I have a UITextField and when I get the `MyTextField.text` value, instead of just the text value it prints

> Optional("UITextField Value")

How do I get it to print just the actual text **without the Optional()**, so it is just the text that is in the UITextField. For Example:

```
import UIKit

class FirstViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var MyTextField: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        print(MyTextField.text)
    }
}
```

Let's say the TextField value was "Hello World"
It would print: "optional("Hello World")"

Thank You in advance

Comment: `MyTextField.text!` will give you the value inside `.text` but this is unsafe, you should always use `if let ... else` and `guard` to safely unwrap `Optional` variable

Comment: How could I use if, else and gard to do do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your `MyTextField` is an optional, you will have to unwrap the value in your text before printing it.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let text = MyTextField.text {
        print(text)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Xcode is simply saying it does not know if there is actually text in the textfield. Simply putting

```
print(MyTextField.text!)
```

should do the trick. By putting the exclamation mark there, you are telling Xcode that you know that there is text within the textfield. However, if you put this code and `MyTextField.text` does not exist, you will receive a crash. To prevent this, do something like this:

```
if MyTextField.text != nil {
    print(MyTextField.text!)
}
```

Hope this helps.